# How can I add sql statement in C/C++ Eclipse Editor?

Tags: eclipse, proc

I need to add a few sql statement in C/C++ Editor because I'am using Pro*C/C++

How can i add that in C/C++ Editor using Eclipse?

I am using Eclipse Kepler

Comment: What do you mean? Are you interested in executing SQL queries or do you mean like syntax highlighting or why do you mention Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, adding a new syntax

Comment: do you develop a new Eclipse plug-in and want to add syntax highlighting for it? I don’t get it what you want to do, sorry.

Comment: There is Editor of C/C++ into Eclipse. I would add new syntax into that editor...

Comment: You can open the file with the SQL File Editor (the same as when you create an .sql file and open it, this editor should be available if you download the Eclipse EE package). But then the C/C++ syntax is not highlighted anymore. You can’t have the syntax highlighting for both in one editor. There’s no preference for that in Eclipse.

Comment: The question is for that...

Answer (score -1):

I have found Edit Plus (https://www.editplus.com/).

It's a text editor that suports new syntax added by user.

There is a syntax file for "ProC or C with embedded SQL" (ProC) :
(https://www.editplus.com/dn.php?n=proc2.zip).